# Как спарсить страницу после InvokeMember

Tags: c#

Хочу спарсить контент, но не получается. Выходит так, что `webBrowser1.DocumentText;` содержит "код" страницы которая загрузилась, но не видит изменения (в моем случае - клик по элементу, после клика появляется div. Все это я наблюдаю в форме, но div в документ не записывается)

```
        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("event-more-view-3813947").InvokeMember("click");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(str);
            if (doc != null)
            {
                var Text2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//html");
                foreach (var c in Text2)
                {
                    textBox1.Text += c.InnerHtml;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: т.к. используете WebBrowser, то HtmlAgilityPack не нужен.

Comment: у div определен class или id?

Comment: @Stack да, есть. Я пытаюсь всю страницу спарсить, но он непоявляется  в //html

Comment: после `InvokeMember("click")` возможно, что html изменится не сразу, т.к. данные могут загружаться с сервера.

Comment: @Stack а как можно вызвать все из button2_Click, после Invoke()? Т.е подождать загрузки и вызвать void... Пытался но не получается. Ставил Sleep(), не помагает....

Comment: _"после Invoke()? Т.е подождать загрузки"_ -- если после Click что-то добавляется/меняется, то это можно отследить. например проверять количество элементов, или проверять текст, который до нажатия был load, после нажатия стал loading, после загрузки стал load.

Comment: _"Т.е подождать загрузки"_ -- чтобы дождаться изменение DOM можно создать отдельный поток и проверять изменение значения. пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488876/196972)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocumentText - это как `View Page Source` в браузере.
В DocumentText находится html, который был загружен при вызове Navigate или при изменении значения DocumentText. Если после загрузки были внесены изменения в DOM, то их можно получить через OuterHtml.

```
void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  textBox1.Text = webBrowser1.Document.Body.Parent.OuterHtml;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте:

```
string str = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("html")[0].OuterHtml;
```

Возвращает html на момент вызова.

Comment: Да, работает. Буду очень благодарен, если в 2х словах объясните почему DocumentText не обновляется, а ваш метод - работает :)

Comment: @LittleFox _"почему DocumentText не обновляется"_ -- см. мой ответ.