# Как отследить изменения в Document (webBrowser)?

Tags: c#, winforms

Загружается страница, после того как она полностью загрузилась, делается клик по элементу и появляется блок с текстом. Проблема в том, что у меня все происходит в ручную. Если я вызову функцию с кодом `button2_Click` в `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted`, то `InvokeMember("click")` не успеет сделать свою задачу. Пытался выставить паузу -

```
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("event-more-view-3813947").InvokeMember("click");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        DownloadPage();
```

---

Но почему-то, сразу идет `Sleep()`, а потом сразу `InvokeMember()` и опять уже `DownloadPage();` не грузит страницу, так-как ничего не успело поменяться.

```
        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("event-more-view-3813947").InvokeMember("click");
        }


        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str = webBrowser1.Document.Body.Parent.OuterHtml;
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(str);
            if (doc != null)
            {
                var Text2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='market-details-3813947']");
                foreach (var c in Text2)
                {
                    textBox1.Text += c.InnerHtml;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Winforms или WPF?

Comment: @VladD  Winforms

Comment: Окей, добавил метку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, есть html, который выводит div. При click'е на div в javascript функции запускается таймер и через 3 сек. меняется содержимое этого div.
В WinForms приложении надо загрузить этот html в WebBrowser, вызвать click, дождаться изменение содержимого div и вывести сообщение.

```
// #r "System.Windows.Forms"
using System.Windows.Forms;

var html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function update() {
           var s = event.srcElement;
           setTimeout(function() { s.innerText = 'ok'; }, 3000);
        }
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body><div onclick='update()' id='d1'>click me</div></body>
</html>";
```

---

```
var f = new Form() { TopMost = true };
var b = new WebBrowser() {
    ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true,
    DocumentText = html,
    Parent = f,
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill
};

void waitUntil(Func<bool> test, Action callback) {
    Task.Run(() => {
        while (test()) { Task.Delay(10).Wait(); }
        callback();
    });
}

b.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) => {
    var t = b.Document.GetElementById("d1");
    t.InvokeMember("click");
    waitUntil(() => t.InnerText == "click me", () => MessageBox.Show("ok"));
};
f.ShowDialog();
```

---

**UPDATE**

Если при нажатии на div добавляется тег с классом market-details-3813947, то надо добавить метод querySelector

```
// #r "System.Windows.Forms"
using System.Windows.Forms;

var html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
        <script>
        function update() {
           var s = event.srcElement;
           var t = '<div class=" + "\"market-details-3813947\"" + @">new</div>';
           setTimeout(function() { s.innerHTML = t; }, 3000);
        }
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body><div onclick='update()' id='d1'>click me</div></body>
</html>";
```

---

```
var f = new Form() { TopMost = true };
var b = new WebBrowser() {
    ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true,
    DocumentText = html,
    Parent = f,
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill
};

void waitUntil(Func<bool> test, Action callback) {
    Task.Run(() => {
        while (test()) { Task.Delay(10).Wait(); }
        callback();
    }).ContinueWith(t => { if (t.Exception != null) Console.WriteLine(t.Exception); });
}
object querySelector(HtmlElement d, string selector) {
    var r = d.Document.Body.InvokeMember("querySelector", new[] { selector });
    if (r is DBNull) return null;
    return r;
}

b.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) => {
    var t = b.Document.GetElementById("d1");
    t.InvokeMember("click");
    waitUntil(
      () => querySelector(t, ".market-details-3813947") == null,
      () => MessageBox.Show("ok"));
};
f.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: В моем случае диалоговое окно появляется только при t.InnerText == "", () => MessageBox.Show("ok")
Т.е опять что-то не так :(.

Comment: @LittleFox если `market-details-3813947` добавляется в html после нажатия на `event-more-view-3813947`, то  надо вызывать querySelector. -- добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Помог `Timer`

```
public bool completed = false;
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (completed == false) { 
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("event-more-view-3768720").InvokeMember("click");
                completed = true;
                timer1.Interval = 3000;
                timer1.Enabled = true;
                timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            }
        }
        void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();  
            MessageBox.Show("Stoped");
            string str = webBrowser1.Document.Body.Parent.OuterHtml;
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(str);
            if (doc != null)
            {
                var Text2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='market-details-3768720']");
                foreach (var c in Text2)
                {
                    textBox1.Text += c.InnerHtml;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var body = wb.Document.GetElementById("targetId");
body.AttachEventHandler("onpropertychange", AjaxContainerLoadData);
clickLink.InvokeMember("click");

private void AjaxContainerLoadData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var wb = sender as WebBrowser;
    ...
}
```